# Android custom UI for app

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anybody have any idea on how to approach custom UI for an app?
I mean, there are several amazing looking apps out there, that DO NOT look like they were made using the layouts and views offered by Android.
Such as: [PIE UI](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/03/pie-ui-revisited-silver-dark-is-a-custom-ui-that-reminds-us-why-android-is-awesome/),
[Color in the Dark](http://mycolorscreen.com/2012/04/19/citd-v2/), or look at this collection [Collection](http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/customization-roundups/awesome-homescreen-setups-for-your-inspiration/)
I basically want to know how to draw custom shapes and arrange them while making them clickable.
I know how to draw regular custom shapes, but how do I arrange them how do I make really custom shapes like parts of a circle or an ellipsis or even irregular shapes?

I know a little Photoshop, so there I can draw whatever my imagination lets me, but how do I integrate yhe images/shapes drawn there in the UI since I cannot place a shape by it's coordinates? Not all shapes can be placed inside a rectangle, because some parts might overlap. So how are they doing it?

Comment: i dont know if this is any good, but from reading around your looking for per-pixel collision, maybe this link will help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524105/Per-pixel-collision-detection-on-Android-devices

Comment: I nearly want to be able to draw my images on a canvas and then catch touch events on those images (or shapes). I do not need animation, nor do I need the mechanics of a colission detector. Thanks though for the link, it might be useful on future projects